# Selenium JS sendKeys 2 or More Inputs

Tags: javascript, selenium

I'm try to log in in a Website (Instagram) with the following code:

```
driver.wait(selenium.until.elementLocated(selenium.By.name(loginForm.user))).then(function (userID) {
        driver.wait(selenium.until.elementLocated(selenium.By.name(loginForm.password))).then(function (pwd) {
            pwd.sendKeys(password);
            userID.sendKeys(name);
            pwd.submit();
            driver.wait(selenium.until.elementLocated(selenium.By.className('GAMXX'))).then(function (popupSave) {
                popupSave.click();
                next();
            })
        });
    });
```

I tried too:

```
 driver.wait(selenium.until.elementLocated(selenium.By.name(loginForm.user))).then(function (userID) {
        userID.sendKeys(name);
        driver.wait(selenium.until.elementLocated(selenium.By.name(loginForm.password))).then(function (pwd) {
            pwd.sendKeys(password);
            pwd.submit();
            driver.wait(selenium.until.elementLocated(selenium.By.className('GAMXX'))).then(function (popupSave) {
                popupSave.click();
                next();
            })
        });
    });
```

And the result is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJedJ.png)
The first input is typed and removed

I'll try with/without promise, adding selenium.Key.TAB and doesn't work. Any clues?

Comment: you are not sending the value to user field. It should be `userID.sendKeys(name);`, you can do this below `pwd.sendKeys(password);`

Comment: For some reason i deleted this line for do the question, my current code still failing is this with this userID.sendkeys(name); Thanks for the help anyway @supputuri. Do you know another way for do the same?

Comment: I would try dispatch event after entering the user name. Find out the event attached to the element and dispatch the event , I guess it might be `change` or `key press` event.